# ImageView selector

Tags: android

I have a view group that contains an image view. The view group is clickable and launches another activity. I want to set a selector for the image view, so that it changes its source image when sele cted, but I don want the image view to intercept the click event. I want the view group to deal with the event. The image view should only change its drawable. Is that possible?

Thank you in advance,

Gratzi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could set a click listener onto the ImageView that doesn't do anything. That way the ImageView will intercept the click that normally the view group gets.

Comment: Isn't there an easy way of specifying that the view doesn't want to deal with the click event and to pass the event to the parent? An xml attribute, or something?

Comment: If you don't add a handler it will be propagated to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `TouchListener` you can specify if the event is consumed or not. I use this code to press things within a `GroupView`, but the `GroupView` itself handles the `OnClick`

```
new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            lefter.setPressed(true);
            contents.setPressed(true);
        }
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || !isInside(v, event)) {
            lefter.setPressed(false);
            contents.setPressed(false);
        }
        return false;
    }

    //...

}
```

The returned boolean is documented as follows: "True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise. "